# How to remove the vector object from the map

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

I have a map `std::map<int, std::vector<Data>>myMap` and my structure is defined as follows.

```
        struct Data
        {
         int x;
         int z;
         int y;
        };
```

in myMap key is int and value is vector of structure

I'm given with x and key value.
I want remove the object from the vector where the key and x value of the vector object matches

I have tried by giving all the x,y,z values of the structure :

`myMap[123].erase(std::remove(myMap[123].begin(), myMap[123].end(), {1,2,3}), myMap[priority].end());`

But Here only X value will be given.

I have tried to write a function as follows :

```
void deleteByx(int x)
{
        for (std::map<int,std::vector<Data>>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
        {
            std::vector<Data> list = it->second;
            for (std::vector<Data>::iterator vec_it = list.begin(); vec_it != list.end(); vec_it++)

            for(int index = 0;index < list.size();index++)
            {
                if (vec_it->x == x)
                {
                    list.erase(vec_it);
                }
            }


        }
}
```

but here the function deletes the element from the local vector `list`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried  myMap[123].erase(std::remove(myMap[123].begin(), myMap[123].end(), {1,2,3}), myMap[priority].end()); but it was giving the error saying  no matching function for call to ‘remove(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, ). But If tried using std::remove for the map where the value is vector of int it was working for me

Comment: and what is wrong with that? It is much easier to give an answer if you include a [mcve] and explain how it does not work as expected

Comment: also I'm not given with all the variables of the structure only x value is given

Comment: Why not make the key a `std::pair<int, int>`, where the second value is `x`?

Comment: No ,this is only specific case where I'm considering x value to delete.

Comment: I have tried.  `void deleteByx(int x)
{
        for (std::map<int,std::vector<Data>>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
        {
            std::vector<Data> list = it->second;
            for (std::vector<Data>::iterator vec_it = list.begin(); vec_it != list.end(); vec_it++)

            for(int index = 0;index < list.size();index++)
            {
                if (vec_it->x == x)
                {
                    list.erase(vec_it);
                }
            }


        }
}` it only deletes the element of the local list vector not of map.

Comment: edit your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62758595/edit code in comments is unreadable

Comment: Why are you iterating over your vector in two different ways, nested? Is that really the code? Anyway, it's a typo because you just omitted the reference `&` on `list`. Then you should probably use the `erase`-`remove` idiom instead of rolling your own loop. Case in point: it's [invalid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to `erase` at `vec_it` and then keep using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the time. I have tried with the following code and it worked for me.

```
for ( itr = myMap[key].begin(); itr != myMap[key].end(); ++itr)
    {
        if (itr->x == 1)
        {
            myMap[key].erase(itr);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have access to the actual data item, then you need to get a reference to that item.  Instead, your current code gets a copy of the vector.

Thus this line:

`std::vector<Data> list = it->second;`

Should be:

`std::vector<Data>& list = it->second;`